# Html.BeginForm routing to Web Api

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get my page to post to my Web API controller, rather than my Area/Controller/Action.  Here is what I have so far, I have tried using both Html.BeginForm and Ajax.Begin Form :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("", "", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Url = "api/Standing" }, new { id = "frmStandingAdd", name = "frmStandingAdd" }))

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "api/Standing", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmStandingAdd", name = "frmStandingAdd" }))
```

But I cannot get either to post to the root ie `http://domain/api/Standing`, instead both post to the Area ie `http://domain/Areaname/api/Standing`.  How do I get it to post correctly?

**Update:** Here are my routes for the relevant area :

```
public override string AreaName
{
    get
    {
        return "Areaname";
    }
}

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    string defaultLocale = "en-US";

    context.MapRoute(
        "Areaname_default",
        "{languageCode}/Areaname/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { languageCode = defaultLocale, controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    context.MapRoute(
        "History",
        "{languageCode}/Areaname/{controller}/{action}/{year}",
        new { controller = "History", action = "Season", year = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

And my Web API routes :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApi",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiWithAction",
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{season}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Please post your `routes`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can explicitly tell the links to post to the root by including the leading slash:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("", "", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Url = "/api/Standing" }, new { id = "frmStandingAdd", name = "frmStandingAdd" }))

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "/api/Standing", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmStandingAdd", name = "frmStandingAdd" }))
```

Comment: Thanks, the Ajax.BeginForm works, but the Html.BeginForm does not, so I went with Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: Had to remove the first / from "/api/Standing" in Html.BeginForm. Mvc seems to be adding one by default, so otherwise I would get //api/standing

Answer (score 8):

You would need to use `BeginRouteForm` as link generation to Web API routes always depends on the route name. Also make sure to supply the route value called `httproute` as below.

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { controller="Entries", httproute="true" }))
```

Comment: This actually helped me out. Was searching this for a long time.